# Detecting Object in FOV camera in BGE

Tags: python, game-engine, camera

I am trying to detect if an object is visible from a camera (i.e. not only if it is in its FOV but also it should not be behind another object).

I was looking at using the `cam.boxInsideFrustum` and `own.rayCastTo`

Now, the issue I am encountering is that the `cam.boxInsideFrustum` does not seem to be providing the right information.

I created a function that generates a bounding box of a mesh (I could not find a ready to use function)

The `bounding_box_str` (structure) is a dictionary that has, as a key the name of the object (`own['P']`) (I have many moving objects running around the environment where the property `P` is a unique identifier) and as the value a list of vertices.

`check_max` and `check_min` are obvious functions.

```
def bounding_box(own):

    global bounding_box_str

    temp_box_str = []

    X = [math.inf, -math.inf]  
    Y = [math.inf, -math.inf] 
    Z = [math.inf, -math.inf]

    transform = own.worldTransform

    for i in range(own.meshes[0].getVertexArrayLength(0)):
        vertex = transform * own.meshes[0].getVertex(0,i).getXYZ()
        X[1] = check_max(vertex.x, X[1])
        Y[1] = check_max(vertex.y, Y[1])
        Z[1] = check_max(vertex.z, Z[1])

        X[0] = check_min(vertex.x, X[0])
        Y[0] = check_min(vertex.y, Y[0])
        Z[0] = check_min(vertex.z, Z[0])

    for i in range(8):
        str = "{0:03b}".format(i)
        temp_box_str.append([X[int(str[0])],Y[int(str[0])],Z[int(str[0])]])

    bounding_box_str[own['P']] = temp_box_str
```

Then, later in another function I have

```
if cam.boxInsideFrustum(bounding_box_str[own['P']]) == cam.INSIDE:
```

As you can clearly see, I just adapted the example code from:

https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78c_release/bge.types.KX_Camera.html?highlight=cam#bge.types.KX_Camera.boxInsideFrustum

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work at all.

I was not able to check if the bounding box computation above is really correct. I tried to create a bounding box around the object with the vertices (adding faces) in the `bounding_box_str` above, but without success. I understand it might not be possible to create a new mesh on the fly in BGE.

I was trying to get a feeling of what the frustum of the camera is, but I understand this cannot be visualized (yet).

I then abandoned this idea and decided to check if any point of the mesh (or the centroid of the mesh) representing the object is in the camera image plane.

I tried the function in `bpy_extras.object_utils` called `world_to_camera_view`, but as I am passing object from the BGE it complaints that the object does not have a `matrix_world` transform.

I liked the `world_to_camera_view' as it provides a normalized output, thus the same code works for multiple cameras.

I abandoned that idea and decided to use the methods in the camera class. There is a `getWorldtoCamera()` transform or the `cam.world_to_camera` (they seem to be equivalent), but it does not seem to provide what I need. The snippet of code I used is the following:

```
transform = own.worldTransform

for i in range(own.meshes[0].getVertexArrayLength(0)):
    vertex = cam.world_to_camera * transform * own.meshes[0].getVertex(0,i).getXYZ()
```

`vertex` however is an X,Y,Z vector (I would have expected a 2D vector). Furthermore, I am not sure how to check from there if the point is indeed in the image plane of the camera.

The `rayCastTo` works well to detect things in between. So that part seems to be OK

If anyone has any suggestion/pointer to possible alternative methods, I would really appreciate it a lot!!!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: BTW: I also tried to use `if cam.pointInsideFrustum(own.position) != cam.OUTSIDE:` (I thought maybe the box i created is not valid or something) ... nothing. It does not work either. Frustrating!!!

Comment: OK made some progress: 1) I now understand why the vertex mapped back to the camera space has 3 coordinates as it give a point inside the camera 'pyramid' then one needs to check if it is between the two clipping planes and within the image plane. Not sure how to get those info from the camera class though. Examples seem to only show using bpy. 2) I read in some other blog that the reason the `____InsideFrustum` might not be working is because the camera is not initialized (`projective_matrix` not initialized). Anyone has any experience with that? Thx!

Comment: Furthermore the `if cam.pointInsideFrustum(own.position) != cam.OUTSIDE` above gives always `True` !! Even for objects that are not in the FOV ...

Comment: OK, SOLVED THE PROBLEM: One needs to render from all the cameras using viewports. In this way the `projection_matrix` (not `projective_matrix` as above, sorry) is set correctly (otherwise is just an Id matrix). You can find how to do that here [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-NC7ZtKcG1U], 2) the `cam.OUTSIDE` has a value 2 whereas the `pointInsideFrustum` only returns a `True (1)` or `False (0)`. I did not realize that (and it make sense as it would not be possible to detect a point to be at the boundary :-), which is instead possible for a box or sphere).